# How to manage a multiple BLE writeCharacteristic and readCharacteristic call?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am currently working to Android application which communicates with a CC2650 Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) device.

I have to need to make a `writeCharacteristic` call followed by multiple `readCharacteristic` calls with a function. This order can be reversed without affecting functionality.

---

**Question 1:** When only a `writeCharacteristic` or `readCharacteristic` are called individually the software works as expected. But software doesn't seem to work when the calls are made in sequence.

Below is the code.

---

Code section referencing `writeCharacteristic` code (UI Thread)

```
final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic_select = mGattCharacteristicMap.get("hotstate");
    if (characteristic_select != null) {
        final int charaProp = characteristic_select.getProperties();
        if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE) > 0) {
            String strData = "00";
            int len = strData.length();
            byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
                data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(strData.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                        + Character.digit(strData.charAt(i + 1), 16));
            }
            characteristic_select.setValue(data);
            mBLE_Service.writeCharacteristic(characteristic_select);
        }
    }
```

---

Code section with readCharacteristic (UI Thread). Note Multiple read call, which are queued

```
final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic_time = mGattCharacteristicMap.get("timestate");
if (characteristic_time != null) {
        final int charaProp = characteristic_time.getProperties();
        if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ) > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                mBLE_Service.readCharacteristic(characteristic_time);
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                    }
                }, 5000);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Code for `readCharacteristic`

```
 public void readCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {

        // Queue the characteristic to read, since several reads are done on startup
        characteristicQueue.add(characteristic);

        // If there is only 1 item in the queue, then read it. If more than 1, it is handled
        // asynchronously in the callback
        if((characteristicQueue.size() <= 1)) {

            mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
        }

    }
```

---

Code for `writeCharacteristic`

```
  public void writeCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return;
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);

}
```

---

Code for `onCharacteristicRead`

```
       @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                     BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                     int status) {
        // Read action has finished, remove from queue
        characteristicQueue.remove();

        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
        }

        // Handle the next element from the queues
        if(characteristicQueue.size() > 0)
            mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(characteristicQueue.element());
        else if(descriptorWriteQueue.size() > 0)
            mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptorWriteQueue.element());
    }
```

---

Code for `onCharacteristicWrite`

```
       @Override
    public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        super.onCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status);
        if (status==BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS){
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_WRITE_SUCCESS, characteristic);
            } 
    }
```

**Question 2:** Since I have multiple reads I created a queue to handle. Do you think read and write are causing the issue? If so any suggestion on how to manage and block reads and writes?

Note: Code is for Android API 21 and higher

References:

- [What is “reliable write” in BLE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24485536/what-is-reliable-write-in-ble)
- [onCharacteristicWrite() is being called, but it doesn't always write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109178/oncharacteristicwrite-is-being-called-but-it-doesnt-always-write)

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: @Submersed So if I do `writeCharacteristic` followed by `readCharacteristic` (multiple read calls) the `readCharacteristic` calls are not serviced. If reverse the then the `writeCharacteristic` are serviced. if necessary I can post the logcat. To keep the post manageable  I have left out some details. BTW thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are half-way there by understanding you need a queue. But you must make sure you use it for ALL GATT operations. See my full answer: [Android BLE BluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor() return sometimes false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47097298/android-ble-bluetoothgatt-writedescriptor-return-sometimes-false/47103533#47103533).

Comment: Your suggestion queue worked. Thank you for the response.Also read some of your other post. Also I wonder why the -1 vote. Anyhow I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you need to wait for the callback to return before writing/reading again. Similar problem for the answer here.

[Android BLE BluetoothGattDescriptor writeDescriptor issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52208563/android-ble-bluetoothgattdescriptor-writedescriptor-issue/52208865#52208865)

Except instead you may need to wait for the readDescriptor/Characteristic in addition to the write.